# Pulling Github teams from user log in

Tags: java, api, github, login-control

I am trying to find a java library that will give me the ability to pull a user's Github teams based on their log in email. I am creating the backend for a website and would like the user to have the option to pick their teams from a drop down. I have looked through multiple API documentations, including [Github's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#get-team)
but I cannot figure out how to use this in my java code. Does anyone have any good library recommendations for this implementation? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a [GitHub wrapper](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/) for the API and implemented this into my code.